# How to do Linux-like file modifications on Windows command line?

Tags: windows, text-editing, find-and-replace, command-line

I need to do some more or less easy replacements in certain files on Windows machines. This is part of an automated software build process, so to be able to reproduce it on all build mashines I absolutely have to rely on tools that are part of windows Windows Vista and Windows 7. No additional software installation (even if it just requires copying onto the mashine) is possible.

I just need to replace one guid with another and additionaly replace a part-string another easy to recognize pattern.

What would you suggest? Are there any easy commandline-only tools to do that in windows or do I have to write a powershell script? If the latter, do you have a good reference on powershell (never used it? ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Windows PowerShell. It's part of the OS since Windows Vista and Windows 7 (can be also installed on Windows XP).
PowerShell is a really powerfull object oriented scripting evironment, based on the .NET Framework, for the Windows operating system (simillar to the Linux Bash).
There is a lot of documentation availible from Microsoft on [how to use PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419).

There is also a good free PowerShell Book availible [here](http://powershell.com/Mastering-PowerShell.pdf).